# Django admin command equivalent for gin golang

Tags: django, go, web, go-gin

I want to write a script a to migrate data from one table to another using gin golang. The dataset is quite big so I can't create an API endpoint and do it as it will get timed out. I am looking an equivalent of `django admin` commands for golang that can help me to connect to the database easily and perform these task.

Comment: you can use this package https://github.com/smallnest/gen

Comment: Is this task related to go or django? Looks like a pure database task, which might be best solved with database tools. Which DB are you using?